# Filereader.readasDataUrl is not throwing error when file is uploaded through lightning-file-upload

Tags: lightning-web-components, fileupload, lightning-file-upload

I have an LWC component which takes xlsx/xlsm file as input and sends the file data to an API as input. Initially, I used lightning-input with type=file which is working as expected for files <3MB and I was unable to work with files >3MB. So I decided to use lightning-file-upload here.

```
HTML file
<lightning-file-upload
     accept=".xlsx, .xlsm"
     multiple={setmultiplefiles}
     label="Insert File"
     onuploadfinished={openfileUpload}>
</lightning-file-upload>
```

```
JS File
openfileUpload(event) {
        console.log(event.target.files);
        console.log(event.target.files[0]);
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = () => {
            var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1]
            this.fileData = {
                'filename': file.name,
                'base64': base64,
                'recordId': this.recordId
            }
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

For lightning-file-upload:
I see [object Object] in first console log and fails with error "cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')". After removing the second log statement, I'm getting this error "[Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob']" exactly in the last line(reader.readAsDataURl(file);) and

For lightning-input: (Working fine)
I see [object FileList] in console log.

I have referred many related solutions and nothing seems to work. Please provide any solution or suggest any other alternatives to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time `uploadfinished` event fires, the files have already been uploaded to the server. This component takes care of reading the file and uploading those files to Salesforce. The event will contain an Array of the `name` and `documentId` of the successfully uploaded files in the `detail` property. You cannot use `FileReader` on files from `lightning-file-upload`, because the results are not `File` or `Blob` objects.